# Problems with getting context

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I made an application that works with play services. I tested my app on HTC 310, nexus, lenovo p780 and some other devices. It doesn't crash at all. I have installed Crashlytics and recieve some weird crash report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
       at com.preferences.iaps.IabHelper.queryPurchases(IabHelper.java:829)
       at com.preferences.iaps.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:557)
       at com.preferences.iaps.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:521)
       at com.preferences.iaps.IabHelper$2.run(IabHelper.java:614)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I get this error from samsungs like s4, s5. Is there a problem with these devices or there is a problem in the app?

Here is an example when i call and pass context to Iabhelper:

```
   @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            mActivity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setRetainInstance(true);

            mHelper = new IabHelper(mActivity, base64EncodedPublicKey);
            mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
            mHelper.startSetup(this);
        }
```

Here is what is causing the threw null pointer exception: (line 829):

```
 logDebug("Package name: " + mContext.getPackageName());
```

This is where I get the context (same class where error)

```
public IabHelper(Context ctx, String base64PublicKey) {
        mContext = ctx.getApplicationContext();
        mSignatureBase64 = base64PublicKey;
        logDebug("IAB helper created.");
    }
```

Comment: Maybe post actual code that trows that NullPointer up there.

Comment: @adminral : Where the mContext suddenly comes from? What is logDebug function? Do post the relevant code for the solution.

Comment: If you are passing a `Context` then why `mContext = ctx.getApplicationContext();`? Why not `mContext = ctx;`? You rarely should actually need `getApplicationContext()`. Especially when you are already passing a `Context`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the same issue if you use the following:

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(getActivity(), base64EncodedPublicKey);
```

**EDIT**
I have noticed the error is in your class:

> com.preferences.iaps.IabHelper.queryPurchases(IabHelper.java:829)

Are you sure you have persisted the context variable in the constructor if the IabHelper, and are using the same variable in the queryPurchases?

**EDIT2**

> logDebug("Package name: " + mContext.getPackageName());

mContext is null in the class - you need to make sure you set it in the constructor of IabHelper

Comment: The problem that it was same issue with getActivity(), only thing i dont understand is the device  broken or bad code ???

Answer (score 0):

try `getActivity().getApplicationContext();`